# "sans raison" vs "sans raison aucune" vs "sans aucune raison"?

Tags: grammaire, expressions-idiomatiques

I encountered this sentence in *Astérix* and was uncertain about the grammar:

> ...et des gaulois de ta tribu, sans raison aucune se sont amusés à le décourager!

I would have expected *sans aucune raison*. ChatGPT tells me it works both ways, but it couldn't adequately explain the nuance. Can you also omit *aucune* altogether and just go with *sans raison*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Sans raison aucune*** is more literary, especially here because *sans raison* is located before the verb.

The meaning is the same and *aucune* can be omitted.

A more usual word ordering can be:

> *[...] des gaulois de ta tribu se sont amusés à le décourager sans (aucune) raison*.